# System.out.println command printing on the same line

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code in which I made a class List which is my version of an array list, with a method called "displayList()" which prints in the console the content of the list.
After that, in the main method I have a System.out.println command that was supposed to print a string on the next line after the content of the list (after the list.displayList() invocation). Yet, the System.out.println command prints the string on the same line.

Here is my code:

```
public class List {
    int [] initialArray = new int[10];
    int cursor = 0;


    public int [] add(int x) {
        if(cursor == initialArray.length) {
            int [] temp = new int [initialArray.length + 10];
            for (int i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = initialArray[i];
            }
            initialArray = temp;
        }
        initialArray[cursor++] = x;

        return initialArray;
    }
  

   public void displayList() {
       for (int i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(initialArray[i]);
           if(cursor - 1 > i) {
               System.out.print(", ");
           }else {
               break;
           }
       }
   }


public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list = new List();
        list.add(10);
        list.add(20);

        list.displayList();
        System.out.println("Abracadabra");

    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
10, 20Abracadabra
```

I do not understand why the result of list.display() and Abracadabra are on the same line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add an empty `System.out.println()` at the end of `displayList`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(" Abracadabra");` prints a new line at the end of the output but doesn't starts with a new line so in displayList you should do something like this

```
public void displayList() {
       for (int i = 0; i < initialArray.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(initialArray[i]);
           if(cursor - 1 > i) {
               System.out.print(", ");
           }else {
               break;
           }
   
       }
       System.out.println(); //< adds a new line after list output
   }
```

Comment: Or just `System.out.println();`. I'd also discourage using hard-coded line separators unless you really need them. I'd much rather use `System.out.printf("%n")`, because the `%n` will be replaced by the system line separator.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to be more specific